# ¿Como acomodar checkboxes en linea?

Tags: html, css, diseño

¿Como puedo acomodar en linea varios checkboxes, sin necesidad de usar (X) sections dentro de un section container y luego usar CSS para centrar y dar estilo?
No pongo ejemplo pero pues basicamente el navegador lo pone en vertical Yo lo necesito en horizontal...
¡Ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

```html
<label>Opcion 1<input type="checkbox" value="val" name="name"></label>
<label>Opcion 2<input type="checkbox" value="val" name="name2"></label>
<label>Opcion 3<input type="checkbox" value="val" name="name3"></label>
```

HTML por defecto los pone horizontales, si no te lo pone asi entonces revisa los archivos CSS que hayas indexado.

Comment: ¿Y para agregarles un margen Ivan?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un div algo asi: `<div class="check-margin">/*Checkboxes*/</div>` y en la etiqueta `<style>` pones algo
 `.check-margin{ 
                         margin: auto; 
padding: auto;}` y ahi le puedes poner el resto de modificadores que llegues a necesitar

Answer (score 0):

una pregunta disculpen ami no me genera eso yo lo construyo diferente por medio de una funcion de js, ya que recibo informacion desde php y construyo un formulario en un modal de checksbox dejo mi codigo haber si me pueden ayudar

```js
function abrirPopupAsignarDistribuidor(){
    var htmlChecks = "";
    var htmlChecksConMonedero = "";
    var htmlChecksConMonederoMonto = "";

     var jsonData = {
      "idUsuario": idUsuarioAdministrarGlobal,
      "platformType": "CerCrm"
    }

    showMessageOverlay("CARGANDO...", "<?=$pointer;?>images/cargando.gif", "200", "200", "sending");

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "<?=$pointer;?>backend/backend_usuario_consulta_asignar_distribuidor.php",
      data: jsonData,
      success:function(data){
        var resultadoMostrar = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(resultadoMostrar);   
        if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "fallo"){
          if(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"] == ""){
            $(".textoMensaje").text("ERROR.");
          }
          else{
            $(".textoMensaje").text(resultadoMostrar["mensaje"]);
          }

          $("#msj").modal("toggle");

          $(".contenidoUsuarioMonedero").html("");
          closeMessageOverlay();
        }
        else if(resultadoMostrar["codigo"] == "exito"){
          var resultados = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["distribuidoresNo"];
          var resultadosConMonedero = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["distribuidorDisponible"];
          var resultadosConMonederoMonto = resultadoMostrar["objetoRespuesta"]["distribudoresNoDisponible"];

          for(var i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
            var asignar                = resultados[i];
            var distribuidorSinMonedero      = asignar["distribuidorSinMonedero"];
            var idDistribuidorSinMonedero    = asignar["idDistribuidorSinMonedero"];
            var logoDistribuidorSinMonedero  = asignar["logoDistribuidorSinMonedero"];
            nombreComercialSinMonederoGlobal = asignar["nombreComercial"];

             htmlChecks +=
             "<br>"+
             "<label><input type='checkbox'  name='distribuidorAsignado' id='distribuidorAsignado' value='"+idDistribuidorSinMonedero+"'/><span class='checkbox'>"+distribuidorSinMonedero+"<br>"+"<img width = 80px; src='../images/distribuidores/"+logoDistribuidorSinMonedero+"'alt='logo de distribuidor'>"+"</span></label>"+
             "<br>";
          }
}
```

[image: me muestra como en forma vertical aun poniendole la etiqueta label, me podrian ayudar???]

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/331916)